# Report time changes when report exported to excel in ax 2012

Tags: axapta

When I generated trial balancereport initially it will take system time when I export to excel the time becomes changing.

Please suggest a solution.

REPORT WITH CORRECT TIME
[image: REPORT WITH CORRECT TIME]

AFTER EXPORTED TO EXCEL
[image: AFTER EXPORTED TO EXCEL]

Answer (score 0):

it might be that the timestamp differs because it is generated twice.

Note that LedgerTrialBalamce uses the following code for the timestamp:

```
 = Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Reports.DataMethodUtility.ConvertUtcToAxUserTimeZoneForUser(Parameters!AX_CompanyName.Value, Parameters!AX_UserContext.Value, System.DateTime.UtcNow, "d", Parameters!AX_RenderingCulture.Value) & vbCrLf & Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Reports.DataMethodUtility.ConvertUtcToAxUserTimeZoneForUser(Parameters!AX_CompanyName.Value, Parameters!AX_UserContext.Value, System.DateTime.UtcNow, "t", Parameters!AX_RenderingCulture.Value)
```

If you want to generate it once and have the same value used in the export file, add a new dateTime field to the report and populate it using :

```
DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime()
```

Then open the report in MS Visual Studio and change the expression for the textbox using your new field.